# Unity Firebase SetvalueAsync() freeze game

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

When I send data to my database as shown below, the editor freezes, what is the reason? Why does the code freeze even though I run it asynchronously?

```
private IEnumerator SetCoinDB(int coinCount)
{
    var DBTask = databaseReference.Child("users").Child(firebaseUser.UserId).Child("coins").SetValueAsync(coinCount + User.Instance.coin);
    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);
    if(DBTask.Exception != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Coin update problem");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Coins updated normally");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:
https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with

With Unity you'll have to be careful to not lock the main thread which is easy to do when introducing co-routines.

Comment: Actually, what I want is to update the database in a different thread. So I want the database to be updated while other codes continue to run.

Comment: Sorry, updated my original post after re-reading your question and code.

Comment: My implementation goes along with this document however i started experiencing freezing when i try to load data from the real time database. It was working just fine yesterday on my phone and in the editor but now i am unable to load any data without the game freezing. Any idea why this is happening?